# Filter results in CoreData by entity description

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I have a very large CoreData table with elements like this one (simplified):

```
@interface Medicament : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * identifier;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@end
```

At some point I want to find elements have the same property (and discard the rest), something like this SQLite sentence:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS count FROM Medicament GROUP BY name WHERE count > 1
```

For this I have this CoreData query:

```
NSFetchRequest* fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Medicament"];
NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Medicament"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSAttributeDescription* identifierDesc = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"identifier"];
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath: @"identifier"];
NSExpression *countExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction: @"count:"
                                                          arguments: [NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName: @"count"];
[expressionDescription setExpression: countExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType: NSInteger32AttributeType];


[fetch setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:identifierDesc, expressionDescription, nil]];
[fetch setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:identifierDesc]];
[fetch setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
NSError* error = nil;
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch
                                                         error:&error];
```

That seems to correctly return a list of dictionaries with the following format:

```
{
    count = 1;
    identifier = 65023;
},
    {
    count = 2;
    identifier = 65025;
},
{
    count = 1;
    identifier = 65027;
}
```

The problem is that I want to discard all the results with a `count` equal to `1`.

I've tried adding a predicate to the fetch hoping that CoreData was smart enough like this:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"count > 1"];
fetch.predicate = predicate;
```

But it crashes with the error `keypath count not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Medicament id=11>`.

Is this even possible using CoreData or do I have to filter the results after fetching from database?

---

This is my current approach for filtering objects already loaded from the database:

```
NSPredicate* filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"count > 1"];
NSArray* filteredResults = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```

But I was hoping that this simple calculation could be performed by CoreData or SQLite, that will probably be much more efficient.

Comment: What you are doing here is setting the predicate to the fetch request whose entity is set to Medicament and so Medicament doesn't have a property named count! You can make a model which has a identifier and a count property fill it with the results you get from coredata and then filter the array of that model with this predicate. So yes I think you will have to fetch results first from coredata and then filter them.

Comment: @NofelMahmood Yes, that was a hopeless attempt. I guess that the database engine would perform that operation much faster than I would do by code. Currently the database has 30k rows, and around 28k will be discarded. So I will load huge amounts of data that I don't need from the database.

Comment: Have you used the "havingPredicate" feature of NSFetchRequest?

Comment: You can reduce the memory overhead by setting fetch request batch size. It is set to 0 by default which in turn brings all the objects of the result in memory.If you set it to say 20 it would bring only 20 objects in memory and next 20 when you try to access them and so on automatically :)

Comment: @pbasdf Yes, using `havingPredicate` made no difference. Same error

Comment: @NofelMahmood That could definitely reduce the memory footprint, but the CPU overhead will be the same. That's currently my implementation until I find another approach by the way.

Comment: ok :) Another idea is to change your datamodel a little bit. I am assuming that in your case multiple Medicament objects can have the same identifier. Why not make another model which has all the unique identifiers and use it as a foreign key in your Medicament object(1 to many relationship). In that case you can fetch identifier objects whose Medicament objects have count greater than one ?

Comment: @NofelMahmood the problem is that the application is already in production for more than 2 years, and in the next update we want to perform some changes, unifying some results that were previously considered distinct. So... changing the current schema is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this is to first fetch the data, and then filter it by count from there.

If you wanted you can add an attribute to the entity called count and then you could use that predicate to filter for the entities you want (in this case count > 1) but you need to add a count attribute in the Medicament entity to do that.

Comment: As you can see in the last lines, that's already what I am doing